# For Smaller values of z the function 1-cos z approaches z^2. How?

Tags: analysis

Is there any typical way to say that a function (anything of this kind) approaches some other comparative function at certain conditions?

Like 1-cos z approaches z^2 when z tends to 0.

Like sin x/x tends to 1 as x tends to 0 (sandwich theorem can be applied to prove this).

But what is the general idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these estimates come from the Taylor expansion of the function. Notice that

$$ \cos z = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4) $$

and so we can approximate $1 -\cos z$ by $z^2/2$ for small enough $z$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $z^2/2$?

Comment: "By $z^2$" should be "by $z^2/2$", right?

Comment: That has been fixed already.